# Elementary OS keeps saying "Updates available" every time i turn on my computer

Tags: updates, appcenter

Everytime i boot up my laptop the AppCenter would show me a notification that updates are available even though i already updated those components already.

Comment: What version of elementary are you running? What happens if you open appcenter and update every app. Does the notification dissapear? Do you see a white screen on the "installed" tab?

Comment: I'm using eOS 6 Odin, and when I open the notif it would take me to the "operating system updates" screen and it usually shows up something something "flatpak runtime locale" and i would press update then it immediately just updates, it happens everyday

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I am getting these quite often. I'm thinking these are updates to flatpaks that are installed.
The way I understood Flatpaks was that they updaed automatically in the background on their launch. But I'm probably confusing that with something else. I'm definitely not a coder and just an end user, lol. But I do know that with Linux you dont HAVE to update something just because there is an update.

It would be nice to have an option to turn off update notification. Simliar to Ubuntu where you can set security updates to automatic and only check for regular updates weekly, monthly or never. Being bombarded with notifications when you first fire up the machine to do work is annoying and distracting.

Comment: You definitely *can* turn off notifications from certain applications, including the App Center. Just head to Notifications → Settings and customize as you like. Afaik there is no simple way to turn on automatic updates, but setting up the commands to do so shouldn't be too hard ;)